# Combining n vectors into one vector of n-tuples

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17, template-meta-programming, range-v3

I'm thinking about a function with signature

```cpp
template<typename ...Ts>
std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>> join_vectors(std::vector<Ts>&&...) {
    //...
};
```

but probably a more general one accepting any iterable instead of just `std::vector` would be good. Probably it would have a signature like this?

```cpp
template<template<typename> typename C, typename ...Ts>
C<std::tuple<Ts...>> join_vectors(C<Ts>&&...) {
    // ...
};
```

However, I'm not at this level yet in C++ (despite doing the same in Haskell would be relatively easy), hence I seek for help.

Unfortunately, Range-v3's `zip` is not at my disposal in this case. I'm tagging it because I think those interested in it are in a better position to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any indexable containers with `size` something like this is possible:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Copy from lvalue containers, move from rvalue containers.
template<typename ...Cs>
auto zip(Cs... vecs) {
    std::vector<std::tuple<typename std::decay_t<Cs>::value_type...>> vec;

    auto len = std::min({vecs.size()...});
    vec.reserve(len);
    for(std::size_t i=0;i<len;++i){
        vec.emplace_back(std::move(vecs[i])...);
    }
    return vec;
};

//Return vector of tuples with & for non-const vecs and const& if const.
template<typename ...Cs>
auto zip_view(Cs&... vecs) {
    std::vector<std::tuple<decltype(vecs[0])...>> vec;
    auto len = std::min({vecs.size()...});
    vec.reserve(len);
    for(std::size_t i=0;i<len;++i){
        vec.emplace_back(vecs[i]...);
    }
    return vec;
};
```

If the containers have properly implemented move constructors, this solution will copy the containers passed as lvalues and move from rvalue ones.
Very slight downside is that lvalue containers are copied whole first instead of only the individual elements.

### Example [[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E4zj9j)]

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
template<typename T, typename...Args>
void print_tuple(const T& first, const Args&... args){
    std::cout<<'('<<first;
    ((std::cout<<','<< args),...);
    std::cout<<')';
}

template<typename T>
struct helper{
using fnc_t = void;
};
template<typename...Args>
struct helper<std::tuple<Args...>>{
using fnc_t = void(*)(const Args&... args);
};
template<typename...Args>
struct helper<std::tuple<Args&...>>{
using fnc_t = void(*)(const Args&... args);
};

template<typename T>
using fnc_t2 = typename helper<T>::fnc_t;

template<typename T>
void template_apply(fnc_t2<T> f, const T& tuple){
    std::apply(f, tuple);
}

template<typename T>
void print_vec(const std::vector<T>& vec){
    for(const auto&e:vec){
        template_apply(print_tuple,e);
        std::cout<<'\n';
    }
}
struct MoveOnlyFoo{
    MoveOnlyFoo(int i):m_i(i){}

    int m_i;
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = nullptr;
};
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const MoveOnlyFoo& foo){
        return o<<foo.m_i;
    }


int main(){
    std::vector v1{1,2,3,4,5,6};
    std::vector v2{'a','b','c','d','e'};
    std::vector v3{1.5,3.5,7.5};
    std::vector<MoveOnlyFoo> vmove;
    vmove.emplace_back(45);
    vmove.emplace_back(46);
    vmove.emplace_back(47);
    const std::vector v4{-1,-2,-3,-4,-5};

    //Move rvalues, copy lvalue.
    print_vec(zip(v1,v2,v3, v4, std::move(vmove)));
    // This won't work since the elements from the last vector cannot be copied.
    //print_vec(zip(v1,v2,v3, v4, vmove));
    std::cout<<"View:\n";
    //View, provides const& for const inputs, & for non-const
    print_vec(zip_view(v1,v2,v3,v4));
    std::cout<<"Modify and print:\n";
    for(auto& [x,y]: zip_view(v1,v2)){
        ++x,++y;
    }
    // Note the view can work with const containers, returns tuple of `const T&`.
    print_vec(zip_view(std::as_const(v1),std::as_const(v2)));
}
```

**Output**

```
(1,a,1.5,-1,45)
(2,b,3.5,-2,46)
(3,c,7.5,-3,47)
View:
(1,a,1.5,-1)
(2,b,3.5,-2)
(3,c,7.5,-3)
Modify and print:
(2,b)
(3,c)
(4,d)
(5,e)
(6,f)
```

Please disregard the readability of the printing code ;)

I modeled it after python `zip` functionality. Note your initial proposal copies the vectors, so the output is a vector with the values moved from the parameters.

Returning an iterable `Cs` is harder because you would have to specify how to insert elements into it, iterators cannot do it on their own.

Getting it work with iterators (but returning still a vector) is a chore, but in theory also possible.

Comment: I'd put the generic version on top in the answer and add `vec.reserve(len);`

Comment: Thanks, and concerning the lazy view on the result, I'd say yes, why not, if you know how to do it?

Comment: Quimby, I've also made a little edit to the question, making the parameters of the function rvalue references, because arguments being temporaries (or local variables I decide I'm ok to `std::move`) is my usecase.

Comment: @Enrico I will try to add the view version. Ok, rvalue inputs are possible, that is only a small change, I already moved the value from the copies.

Comment: @Quimby Oups ... I made the edit when I thought it was _you_ who commented under my comment. Tired eyes. Glad you didn't disagree :-)

Comment: @Quimby I used your nice generic one to make [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rdn3K9). I _think_ it does the right thing except I didn't use iterators to make it work with `std::list` etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am fighting with trying to do this too. The problem is how to forward the nested type based on the universal reference of the container. Your solution moves also from `a,b` which are lvalues. Mine does currently too :(

Comment: Oh, it does? Darn... I didn't setup a test to check what actually happened.

Comment: @Enrico Done, I settled on still calling by value, otherwise universal references get into the way. The only downside is higher peak memory consumption if it even matters. View works nicely though :)

Comment: @Quimby, very nice answer. If you're interested, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995164/does-range-v3s-zip-function-only-work-for-lvalues-if-so-why)'s another Range-v3-related question I just posted.

Comment: @Enrico Thanks, not much experience with boost nor `range-v3` so I will let another else answer it ;)