# Range-v3's zip function works with temporaries coming from other Range-v3's functions but not with others

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17, temporary-objects, range-v3

(This is kind of a follow up to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64985752/combining-n-vectors-into-one-vector-of-n-tuples).)

### Original question

The following code works just fine

```cpp
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <range/v3/view/zip.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    auto vec1 = std::vector<int>{1,2,3};
    auto vec2 = std::vector<std::string>{"uno","due","tre"};

    auto sqrt = [](auto x){ return std::sqrt(x); };
    auto vec3 = vec1 | boost::adaptors::transformed(sqrt);

    for (auto const& i : ranges::views::zip(vec1, vec2, vec3)) {
        // whatever
    }

}
```

but what if I want to avoid storing the result in `vec3`? Ok, without `| to_vector` `vec3` is just a view (right?), so storing it is not a big memory usage concern, but bear with me. Chaging the `for` line to the following does not work

```cpp
    for (auto const& i : ranges::views::zip(vec1, vec2, vec1 | boost::adaptors::transformed(sqrt))) {
```

### The answer from a comment

Based on a comment, I just didn't think much about the problem before posting the question, as the solution as simple as *using `ranges::views::transform` instead of `boost::adaptors::transformed`*.

### I'd still like to understand what was going on

At this point, however, **I'm honestly still interested in understanding what's wrong with the former solution.**

I initially I thought that `ranges::views::zip` couldn't work with temporaries, but the solution above (in *italic*) proves me wrong, as `vec1 | ranges::views::transform(sqrt)` is still a temporary, not an lvalue.

On the other hand, it's also true that `ranges::views::zip(vec1, vec2, std::move(vec3))` fails, where `std::move(vec3)` is also not an lvalue, but an xvalue.

It'd be good if someone could help me understand the peculiarities of `ranges::views::zip` and why it works with some temporaries (I'd say those coming from other Range-v3 functions) but not others (e.g. xvalues coming `std::move` or a true temporary coming from `boost::...`).

Comment: Works with `ranges::view::transform` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81eaf6e9268bc6e5).

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42. I was being stupid. However, I've updated the question, so I don't throw away all this text :P